# connected components of open sets are open

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I would like to prove that the connected components of an open set are open.

Take $U$ an open set in a space $X$ and $U=\cup_\alpha C_\alpha$ where the $C_\alpha$ are the connected components.

Suppose that there exists a $C_\alpha$ which is closed. Then ${C_\alpha}^c$ is open and ${C_\alpha}^c\cap U$ is open. However $$U= U\cap X = U\cap(C_\alpha\cup{C_\alpha}^c) = C_\alpha\cup ({C_\alpha}^c\cap U)$$

which is neither open nor closed. So we have a contradiction.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: There's a problem. If $C_\alpha$ is *not open*, why must that imply that it is *closed*? Note that being *not open* and being *closed* are not the same. Therefore, you need to see what conclusions you can draw from non-openness, or go in for a direct argument.

Comment: What if no such open $U$ exists (unless it is empty)? The proof cannot be correct since connected components are not necessarily open. For that you need extra conditions like: their number is finite (they are closed), or the [space is locally connected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Components_of_Locally_Connected_Space_are_Open).

Comment: If we consider as our topological space the open set itself, then each of its connected components is both open and closed in that topology

Comment: can this be proved in the case of a. manifold? I would like to have this property for the open set of a map

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A space $X$ is locally connected iff a component of an open set is open. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Component_of_Locally_Connected_Space_is_Open) e.g.

So this proof is not correct. Consider the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, then all components are singletons which are never open in $\mathbb{Q}$ (nor in any of its open sets).

Logical fallacies: "not open" does not imply "closed" (sets aren't doors). Components are always closed, so the complement of a component is a union of closed sets, namely all other components,but unions of closed sets need not be closed, only **finite** unions are. So the complement need not be closed, etc.

Comment: can this be proved in the case of a. manifold? I would like to have this property for the open set of a map.

Comment: @tomak A manifold is locally Euclidean, so in particular locally connected. So there it does hold, but with a different proof.

Answer (score 2):

Connected components are open if X is locally connected.
Q is not locally connected, I = { x in Q : 0 < x < 1 } is
open subset and its connected components are the singletons
which are closed and not open.

Comment: can this be proved in the case of a. manifold? I would like to have this property for the open set of a map