# The proof of the fact that $[v,w]=0\;\Rightarrow\;\exp(\varepsilon v) \exp(\theta w)x=\exp(\theta w)\exp(\varepsilon v)x $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, dynamical-systems

I don't quite understand the proof of one of the theorems from the Peter J. Olver's book *Applications of Lie groups to differential equations (2e)* :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't understand why $U$ is open. It is clear for me why the set
$$
\hat W=\{ (\theta,\varepsilon):\; y(\theta,\varepsilon)=\tilde y(\theta,\varepsilon)  \}
$$
is open. Does it coincide with the set $\hat U$? If yes, why? Proposition 1.29 mentioned in the text asserts only the local existence of coordinates in which the vector field $\mathbf v$ is rectifiable. How do we know that the corresponding change of variables is valid for the entire set $\hat W$?
If we do not know this, and $\hat W\ne \hat U$, then, apparently, the "rectifiability set" of the vector field  $\mathbf v$ must be open. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the main confusion is due to the way the theorem is phrased; below I'll paraphrase it in a slightly more rigorous way, which I hope will clarify the broader issue. But before that, shortly:

> Does [$\hat{W}$] coincide with the set $\hat U$?

No, strictly speaking: For $\hat{U}$ one fixes the basepoint $x$, for $\hat{W}$ any anonymous point $y$ close enough to $x$ ought to work.

> Proposition 1.29 mentioned in the text asserts only the local existence of coordinates in which the vector field $\mathbf v$ is rectifiable. How do we know that the corresponding change of variables is valid for the entire set $\hat W$?

You are right that we don't have global (in time) flowboxes necessarily. (e.g. consider the $2$-torus $M=\mathbb{T}^2$ and vertical and horizontal flows on $M$; see e.g. [Dynamics on the torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4452120/169085))

> If we do not know this, and $\hat W\ne \hat U$, then, apparently, the "rectifiability set" of the vector field  $\mathbf v$ must be open. But why?

Even though $\hat{W}$ is not quite the same as $\hat{U}$, it is likely that the openness of $\hat{U}$ is justified in a way similar to the way that makes it clear to you $\hat{W}$ is open.

---

Before paraphrasing the theorem here is some background and notation. Let $M$ be a $C^\infty$ manifold, $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}\cup\{\infty\}$, $X$ be a $C^r$ vector field on $M$. Then by the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for ODE's, there is an open subset $\mathfrak{D}(X)\subseteq \mathbb{R}\times M$ containing $\{0\}\times M$ and a $C^r$ local group action of $\mathbb{R}$

$$\phi:\mathfrak{D}(X)\to M, (t,p)\mapsto \phi_t(p)$$

with the following properties:

1. For any $ p\in M$, $t\mapsto \phi_t(p)$ is the unique solution of the initial value problem $\phi_0(p)=p,\,\, \left.\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}(t,p)=X(p)$.
2. For any $p\in M$, $J_p^X = \{t\in\mathbb{R}\,|\, (t,p)\in \mathfrak{D}(X)\}$ $=\operatorname{proj}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathfrak{D}(X)\,\,\cap \,\,\mathbb{R}\times\{p\})$ is an open interval (which is possibly unbounded),
3. For any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $M_t^X = \{p\in M\,|\, (t,p)\in\mathfrak{D}(X)\}$ $= \operatorname{proj}_{M}(\mathfrak{D}(X)\,\,\cap\,\, \{t\}\times M)$ is an open subset,

Here $\phi$ is the **local flow** of $X$, $X$ is the **infinitesimal generator** of $\phi$, and $\mathfrak{D}(X)$ is the **domain of definition** of $\phi$ (or of $X$, somewhat misleadingly). ("local group action" means that the group property is satisfied within the confines of the domain of definition.)

---

Let me now rephrase the theorem and part of the proof. The main idea is that two local flows commute iff they commute infinitesimally.

**Theorem:** Let $M$ be a $C^\infty$ manifold, $X,Y$ be $C^2$ ($\dagger$) vector fields on $M$. Denote by $\phi$ and $\psi$ the local flows of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Then the following are equivalent:

1. For any $p\in M$, there is an open connected subset $V_p\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ containing $(0,0)$ such that for any $(\epsilon,\eta)\in V_p$ we have $\phi_\epsilon\circ\psi_\eta(p)=\psi_\eta\circ\phi_\epsilon(p)$.
2. $[X,Y]=0$.

($\dagger$) $C^{1,1}$, i.e. $C^1$ with first derivatives satisfying local Lipschitz estimates (see e.g. [Definition of Hölder Space on Manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3324620/169085)), would be sufficient.

**Preamble of Proof of (2.$\implies$1.):** First we have partially defined functions (following the notation from [Notation for "function from a subset of $X$ into $Y$"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3256629/169085))

$$L:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times M   \rightsquigarrow M, (\epsilon,\eta,p)\mapsto \phi_\epsilon\circ \psi_\eta(p),$$

$$R:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times M   \rightsquigarrow M, (\epsilon,\eta,p)\mapsto \psi_\eta\circ \phi_\epsilon(p).$$

Define for any $p\in M$,

$$B_p^{X,Y}=\{(\epsilon,\eta)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\, (\epsilon,\eta,p)\in\operatorname{dom}(L)\cap\operatorname{dom}(R)\} \, ( = \hat{V} \text{ in Olver's notation}),$$

$$A_p^{X,Y}=\{(\epsilon,\eta)\in B_p^{X,Y}\,|\, L(\epsilon,\eta,p)=R(\epsilon,\eta,p)\}  \, ( = \hat{U} \text{ in Olver's notation}).$$

(It is perhaps good conceptually to assemble the $A_p^{X,Y}$'s: putting $\mathfrak{D}(X,Y)=\{(t,p)\in\mathbb{R}^2\times M\,|\, t=(t_1,t_2)\in A_p^{X,Y}\}$, we have a $C^r$ local group action of $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\mathfrak{D}(X,Y)\to M,\, (t,p)\mapsto \phi_{t_1}\circ \psi_{t_2}(p)$.)

Fix a basepoint $p\in M$. First note that $B_p^{X,Y}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Indeed, by definition we have

\begin{align*}
B_p^{X,Y}
=&\{(\epsilon,\eta)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\, (\eta,p)\in\mathfrak{D}(Y), (\epsilon,\psi_\eta(p))\in \mathfrak{D}(X)\}\\
&\cap \{(\epsilon,\eta)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\, (\epsilon,p)\in\mathfrak{D}(X), (\eta,\phi_\epsilon(p))\in \mathfrak{D}(Y)\}\\
= & \left\{(\epsilon,\eta)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\left|\, \eta\in J_p^Y, \epsilon\in J_{\psi_\eta(p)}^X\right\}\right.\\
&\cap \left\{(\epsilon,\eta)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\left|\, \epsilon\in J_p^X, \eta\in J_{\phi_\epsilon(p)}^Y\right\}\right..
\end{align*}

Thus for $(\epsilon,\eta)\in B_p^{X,Y}$, since $\mathfrak{D}(X)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\times M$, there is an open interval $I_1$ and an open subset $N\subseteq M$ such that $(\epsilon,\psi_\eta(p))\in I_1\times N\subseteq \mathfrak{D}(X)$. Since $\psi$ is continuous and $J_p^Y$ is an open interval there is an open interval $I_2\subseteq J_p^Y$ such that $\eta\in I_2$ and $\psi(I_2\times \{p\})\subseteq N$; whence $I_1\times I_2\ni (\epsilon,\eta)$ is included in the first set (which is the "$p$-slice" of $\operatorname{dom}(L)$) defining $B_p^{X,Y}$. A similar argument shows that the second defining set is also open, hence $B_p^{X,Y}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Define $C_p^{X,Y}$ ( = $V$ in Olver's notation) to be the connected component of $B_p^{X,Y}$ containing $(0,0)$. Then $C_p^{X,Y}$ is open both in $B_p^{X,Y}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (see e.g. [connected components of open sets are open](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2587462/169085)). *Say we could show that $A_p^{X,Y}$ is an open subset of $B_p^{X,Y}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^2$).* Then $A_p^{X,Y}\cap C_p^{X,Y}$ (= $U$ is Olver's notation) would be an open subset of $C_p^{X,Y}$. By continuity of the local flows $\phi$ and $\psi$,  $A_p^{X,Y}\cap C_p^{X,Y}$ is also closed in $C_p^{X,Y}$, thus $A_p^{X,Y}\cap C_p^{X,Y}= C_p^{X,Y}$, that is $A_p^{X,Y}\subseteq C_p^{X,Y}$; in particular $A_p^{X,Y}$ would be connected.

Thus it suffices to show that $A_p^{X,Y}$ is open; for this Olver assumes $[X,Y]=0$ (we didn't need to use this until now) and  argues that two sides coinciding not only for the initial condition $p$ but everywhere in a local chart around $p$ is an open condition in the time space, that is, that $\hat{W}$ in your notation is open. Since you seem to have no trouble with this part I'll stop here; the idea is again to use the Existence and Uniqueness theorem.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I got stuck because for some reason I thought that the rectifying change of variables is the same on the entire set, although it may be different at different points. So, we don't need $\hat W$ at all. Thank you for your response!